# How to get values from Ms word merge field using Docx4j Java

Tags: java, docx4j

I am trying to retrieve value from merge field using Docx4j in java.  Currenty I'm retrieving all the contents of the word document using:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage newWordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
    .load(new java.io.File("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test" + i + ".docx"));
MainDocumentPart documentPart = newWordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();                 
System.out.println(documentPart.getContent());
```

This returns a list of contents from the word document. What I'm currently getting is

`MERGEFIELD  lastName  \* MERGEFORMAT   himura`

What I want is to get the value `'himura'` from the merge-field 'lastName'. How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using xpath - see method `documentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath(xpath, false);`

I had similar problem (wanted to replace MergeField with my own content). After long research, I wrote a method that can do it:

```
private void replaceTextWithElement(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, String textToReplace, Collection<Object> newElements) throws JAXBException, Docx4JException {
        final String xpath = "//w:r[w:instrText[contains(text(),'MERGEFIELD') and contains(text(),'" + textToReplace + "')]]";
        final List<Object> foundNodes = mainDocumentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath(xpath, false);
        if (isEmpty(foundNodes)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find textToReplace: \"" + textToReplace + "\" in document, skipping replacement.");
        }

        final R r = (R)foundNodes.get(0);
        final P parent = (P)r.getParent();
        final int index = mainDocumentPart.getContent().indexOf(parent);

        mainDocumentPart.getContent().remove(parent);
        if (newElements != null) {
            mainDocumentPart.getContent().addAll(index, newElements);
        }
    }
```